# Why do we need the this.events[type] || [] line for this to work properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js

guys so I am taking a node.js course and the code I am about to share works perfectly. And I understand it for the most part. In this particular exercise in the course I am taking, we were making our own custom event listeners and emitters to help us better understand how listeners and emitters work in node. As I said, it all makes sense for the most part. The only part that I am trying to wrap my brain around is the first line in the body of the Emitter.prototype.on function expression. Why does it have to be `this.events[type] = this.events[type] || [];` shouldn't  `this.events[type] = [];` work too? I tried it with the latter and it didn't work properly. As I said before, the former does work properly.

I will share the entire code below but I just want to make sure it's clear. The idea is to make it so that multiple functions could be added to a property array in the events object. In this case, the property we are adding to the events object is 'greet' and we are adding two functions to the greet array. Again, my question is why do we have to use a line like `this.events[type] = this.events[type] || [];` shouldn't  `this.events[type] = [];` work too? the latter line is creating an array isn't it? Please help me understand thank you in advance.

**emitter.js code**

```
function Emitter() {
    this.events = {};
};

Emitter.prototype.on = function(type, listener) {
    this.events[type] = this.events[type] || [];
    this.events[type].push(listener);
} 

Emitter.prototype.emit = function(type){
    if(this.events[type]) {
        this.events[type].forEach(function(listener){
            listener();
        });
    }
}

module.exports = Emitter;
```

**app.js code**

```
var Emitter = require('./emitter');

var emtr = new Emitter();

emtr.on('greet', function() {
    console.log('Somewhere out there, someone said hello')

});

emtr.on('greet', function() {
    console.log('A Hello has occurred')

});

console.log('hello');
emtr.emit('greet');
```

Comment: That condition says if `this.events[type]` is truthy use it, otherwise assign an empty array to it. How would an empty Array be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because if you set `this.events[type]` equal to an empty array, when you emit many event it will keep only one listener for each event type **(the last one which was registered)**.

```js
function Emitter() {
    this.events = {};
};

Emitter.prototype.on = function(type, listener) {
    this.events[type] = [];
    this.events[type].push(listener);
} 

Emitter.prototype.emit = function(type){
    if(this.events[type]) {
        this.events[type].forEach(function(listener){
            listener();
        });
    }
}

var emtr = new Emitter();

emtr.on('greet', function() {
    //console.log('Somewhere out there, someone said hello')
});

emtr.on('greet', function() {
    //console.log('A Hello has occurred')

});

console.log(emtr.events);
```

As you can see there are in the `emtr.events` only the last listener which was registered.

But when you set `this.events[type] = this.events[type] || [];` it's simple means set `this.events[type]` equal to it previous value when that event type is already present in the events array otherwise initialize it as an empty array and push in that array a new listener

Comment: Thank you! This response really helped me.

Comment: so how does it know that the first function passed should be placed into an array?

Comment: I think I understand the answer to my last question now. `this.events[type] = this.events[type] || [];` is basically saying `this.events[type]` is equal to `this.events[type]` value in memory and the first time an 'emtr.on('greet', ...)' is invoked `this.events[type]` has no value in memory until the `this.events[type].push(listener);` line. So `this.events[type] = this.events[type] || [];`already set it to an empty array before `this.events[type].push(listener);` adds its first value to it. it took me a while, but your words honestly helped me make it click in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

`this.events[type] = this.events[type] || [];` is an initializing operation here.
at the first time you register `greet`, `this.events` is an empty object. so `this.events[type] = []` is ok. but you cannot reset it to [] when you register `greet` event again.

```
// what happened if use this.events[type] = []
var Emitter = require('./emitter');

var emtr = new Emitter();

// ok, this.event['greet'] = []
// this.event['greet'].push(func1)
emtr.on('greet', function() {
    console.log('Somewhere out there, someone said hello')

});

// you reset this.event['greet'] = []
// this.event['greet'].push(func2)
// !!! lost func1 here
emtr.on('greet', function() {
    console.log('A Hello has occurred')

});

console.log('harro');
emtr.emit('greet');
```

Comment: Thank You! this response as well as the response above really helped me.

Comment: so how does it know that the first function passed should be placed into an array?

Comment: what do you mean? who know?

Comment: when I create the first greet function with the emtr.on method how is it that this first greet function value is automatically placed into an array?

Comment: not automatically, but you did. it is placed into the array when you invoke `this.events[type].push(listener)`. here `this.events[type]` is initialized as an array.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one could help you. If the key in the object "this.events[type]" already exists, then it will just be reset into empty array [].

I will provide you with example code on how the code works line by line if you register 2 events.

```
function Emitter() {
this.events = {};
  
}

Emitter.prototype.on = function (type, listener) {
  this.events[type] = this.events[type] || [];
  this.events[type].push(listener);
  console.log(this.events);
};

Emitter.prototype.emit = function (type) {
  if (this.events[type]) {
    this.events[type].forEach((listener_element) => {
      listener_element();
    });
  }
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var emtr = new Emitter();

emtr.on("greet", () => {
  console.log("Someone said hello");
});
emtr.on("greet", () => {
  console.log("Someone said hello (1)");
});
emtr.emit("greet");

emtr.on("_greet", () => {
  console.log("Someone said _hello");
});
emtr.on("_greet", () => {
  console.log("Someone said _hello (1)");
});
emtr.emit("_greet");
```

OUTPUT:

```
{ greet: [ [Function (anonymous)] ] }
{ greet: [ [Function (anonymous)], [Function (anonymous)] ] }
Someone said hello
Someone said hello (1)
{
  greet: [ [Function (anonymous)], [Function (anonymous)] ],
  _greet: [ [Function (anonymous)] ]
}
{
  greet: [ [Function (anonymous)], [Function (anonymous)] ],
  _greet: [ [Function (anonymous)], [Function (anonymous)] ]
}
Someone said _hello
Someone said _hello (1)
```